# Find the largest disk $f(z) = \frac{1}{1 - z}$ centered around $i$, its Taylor Series and Radius of Convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, solution-verification, taylor-expansion, power-series

I am a bit stuck whether my solution to this question is correct or not, and would like some verification:

> Let $f(z) = \dfrac{1}{1 - z}$. Find the largest disk of convergence centered at $i$, find its Taylor series, and its radius of convergence.

My steps are as follows:

(1) The largest disk of convergence is $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z - i| < 1\}$ and this is the disk on which $f$ is holomorphic.

(2) If $f(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} f^{(n)}(i) \dfrac{(z - i)^n}{n!}$, then
\begin{align*}
f(z) = \dfrac{1}{1 - z} &\Rightarrow f(i) = \dfrac{1}{1 - i} = \dfrac{0!}{(1 - i)^1} \\
f'(z) = \dfrac{1}{(1 - z)^2} &\Rightarrow f'(i) = \dfrac{1}{(1 - i)^2} = \dfrac{1!}{(1 - i)^2} \\
f''(z) = \dfrac{2}{(1 - z)^3} &\Rightarrow f''(i) = \dfrac{2}{(1 - i)^3} = \dfrac{2!}{(1 - i)^3} \\
&\vdots \\
f^{(n)}(z) = \dfrac{n!}{(1 - z)^{n + 1}} &\Rightarrow f^{(n)}(i) = \dfrac{n!}{(1 - i)^{n + 1}}
\end{align*}

Therefore,
\begin{equation*}
f(z) = \dfrac{1}{1 - z} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} f^{(n)}(i)\dfrac{(z - i)^n}{n!} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \dfrac{n!}{(1 - i)^{n + 1}}\dfrac{(z - i)^n}{n!} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(z - i)^n}{(1 - i)^{n + 1}}
\end{equation*}
is the Taylor series of $f(z)$ centered at $z = i$.

(3) The radius of convergence is 1, since from (1), largest disk of convergence is 1, and also, $z \neq 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your series looks okay, but check your radius of convergence. A quick way is to write

$$\frac{1}{1-z}={1\over (1-i)\left(1-\frac{z-i}{1-i}\right)}=\frac{1}{1-i}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( {z-i\over 1-i}\right)^n,\quad \left|{z-i\over 1-i}\right|<1,$$

implying your radius of convergence is $\sqrt 2$: $$\left|{z-i\over 1-i}\right|<1\iff \left|{z-i}\right|<|1-i|=\sqrt 2.$$

Comment: Would it also work for the radius of convergence for me to use: $R = \dfrac{1}{\limsup_n \left|\frac{1}{(1 - i)^{n + 1}}\right|^{\frac{1}{n}}} = \sqrt{2}$

Comment: @user858034 yes

Comment: Thank you for the help!